# neo4j cluster on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

This might sound like a newbie question but I have a neo4j instance running on Amazon cloud. The instance is set to Autoscale at 80% usage. That means Amazon one the usage is reaches 80%, Amazon will create another instance on Neo4j with the same configuration and will keep adding more once this one reaches 80%..
My questions are - 
1) Does this setup on Amazon means we have a cluster of neo4j in place?
2) Do I need to do anything else in order to have neo4j cluster, what I have read is that you need some tool like zookeeper to maintain the cluster..
3) Does this current setup on Amazon will have both instances as Master or will it be more like master/slave setup..

Any help, feedback, suggestions would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance,
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are using Auto Scaling group for Neo4j you need to set a cluster. As @stefan-armbruster mentioned, you need to Neo4j Enterprise edition for that. In that case it's master/slave setup.

Neo4j has its own solution for Cluster management, instead of Zookeeper.

But with AWS and EC2 there are few open question, how to properly deploy Neo4j with Auto Scaling group.

From configuration file perspective
* You need to maintain unique clusterId for each machine in cluster.
* You need to know ip addresses/hostnames of other machines in cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I will have to review what Neo4j folks are suggesting as their cluster solution since I don't want to assume that Amazon AWS will handle it for me..Has anyone implemented Neo4j cluster on Amazon? I would be interested to know how they achieved it.

Comment: @rav It's easy to deploy Neo4j cluster in EC2. But I'm not aware of any solution if you want to use Auto Scaling group for cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j Enterprise edition features clustering, see the [docs on this](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha.html). With some well written scripts around that to configure the new instances properly I don't see a reason why AWS autoscale should not work.